# What is the best way to execute a shell script via network on docker-compose on an image without a network service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm looking for a suggestion for a good way to access a container that is based off an image without a network service, since i'm using docker-compose the containers only talk to one another via network and the container i need just runs a shell script.

Ideas? should i really be considering adding a webserver with my code to just to access a shell script between containers?

Comment: Have you tried using `ssh` to reach the host and then running [`docker attach`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/) to attach to the container?

Comment: from where you want to access to that container ? From the host or from another container that is not specified in the docker-compose template ?

Comment: I'm running php code on the main container so having it create a process to run SSH will be a problem so i avoided that option.
I want to access another container from my main container and the other container doesn't have any ports or services open it's just a runtime container.

So far my solution was to add a webserver to it like apache or something and have that execute a process that calls the script (which is similar to the way i do the same on my main container)

Comment: Your idea is indeed right. You can make two containers to communicate in terms of network opening. But if you don't have a specified port opened on the targeted container, the communication will only limited to connectivity (ping).

Comment: Thanks, i've added apache (in production might switch to nginx) to all the script containers and using docker-compose opened their ports so now i can finally communicate with them :)